# ¿Cuál es el criterio de división de palabras a final de línea?

Tags: ortografía, sílabas

Leyendo un libro vi las siguientes frases así escritas:

> En el congreso del Partido Conservador de 1981, Norman **Te-**
>   **bbit** dijo la célebre fase de que su padre (...)

y

> Ahora que el balón había empezado a rodar, los medios se **afe-**
>   **rraron** entusiasmados a otros casos para confirmar esta imagen
>   distorsionada.

Lo que quiero resaltar aquí es la forma en que las palabras se dividen a final de línea.

Me sorprendió que se separara *Te-bbit*, así como *afe-rraron*. Pensé que las consonantes iguales se separarían (en catalán se hace así).

Por ello, ¿podría alguien detallar cuáles son las reglas para dividir las palabras a final de línea?

Comment: Mientras preparaba la pregunta me di cuenta de que la respuesta está recogida en el fantástico artículo [División de palabras a final de línea de Wikilengua en español](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Divisi%C3%B3n_de_palabras_a_final_de_l%C3%ADnea). Pregunto igualmente para que en este sitio tengamos una referencia al respecto.

Comment: Mientras preparas la respuesta, decir que la norma general es, simplemente, separar por sílabas completas. Así, si la palabra es a/fe/rra/ron, la división será _afe-rraron_. Hay multitud de casos particulares, como el no dejar una letra suelta en ningún lado: _(*)a-cotación_, y que los prefijos se pueden separar enteros: _sub-rayar_ o _su-brayar_. Resulta interesante la división de opiniones que hay sobre las palabras extranjeras: si dividirlas según las reglas del idioma original o las del español. El grupo _-bb-_ no existe en español, de ahí lo raro de _Te-bbit_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incluyo referencias a la página [División de palabras a final de línea](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Divisi%C3%B3n_de_palabras_a_final_de_l%C3%ADnea) de Wikilengua.

> Cuando hay que dividir una palabra al cambiar de renglón, se usa el
>   [guion](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Gui%C3%B3n).  Las normas generales recomiendan que para dividir las
>   palabras a final de línea se siga bien la división [silábica](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/S%C3%ADlaba), bien
>   la división por constituyentes (normalmente los [prefijos](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Prefijo)).

Sobre la pregunta concreta, sí es correcto cómo se hace en el libro la división *afe-rraron*:

> ## ch, ll, rr, gu, qu
>
> Los dígrafos *ch*, *ll*, *rr*, *gu* y *qu* no se separan ni finalizan
>   renglón.
>
> > ca- / chear.   enca- / llado.   ca- / rraspear.   car- / guero.   re- / querimiento.
>
> La única excepción para la *rr* es si este grupo es el resultado de
>   añadir un prefijo que termina en -r a una palabra que comienza por
>   esta misma letra.
>
> > hiper- / realismo.

En cuanto a la división del apellido extranjero:

> ## Palabras extranjeras
>
> Con estas palabras hay distintas opiniones:
>
> Una posición es la que defiende, por ejemplo, la Academia en su
>   *Ortografía* o Leonardo Gómez Torrego en su *Ortografía de uso del español actual*: dicen que no se deben separar palabras de otras
>   lenguas, a no ser que se conozcan las normas de división de palabras
>   de esa lengua. Otra postura es la que defienden ortografías como la
>   *Ortografía de la lengua española* de Larousse: argumentan que las palabras extranjeras se dividirán siguiendo las normas del español,
>   aunque en la lengua originaria sigan normas diferentes.
>
> > cowboy frente a cow- / boy.